# How to extract "=>" to function model

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am fresher here, trying to start using => for functions and can't quite understand the inner part of a function in this code. It does work, wrote it myself, but just want to fully understand how and why.

Is there any other form you could write the exact same code in different "shape"?

I understand how first function extracts to:

```
function deleteNote(NoteID) {
 ...
}
```

But can't figure out how does the inner part work.

```
const deleteNote = noteID => {
        setNote(existingNotes => { return existingNotes.filter((note) => note.id !== noteID);
        })
}
```

Result is fine, just want to clarify what's going on... :)

Comment: read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, that could all be translated to:

```
const deleteNote = function(noteId) {
  setNote(function(existingNotes) {
    return existingNotes.filter(function(note) { 
      return note.id !== noteID;
    });
  });
};
```

If you wrap the part after `=>` in curly brackets `{}`, then you need a return statement to return something, such as in:

```
setNote(existingNotes => {
  return ...;
})
```

If you don't wrap it around curly brackets, then whatever you put after the arrow is what will be returned, such as in:

```
 existingNotes.filter((note) => note.id !== noteID);
```

Take a look at [this short article](https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2015/javascript-lambda-and-arrow-functions/).

Answer (score 2):

To add to Elder's answer, another easier way of getting used to arrow function is by dissecting the calls into separate named functions (which is what we are commonly used to).

So for example:

```
existingNotes.filter((note) => note.id !== noteID);
```

Could also be viewed as:

```
function noteDifferent(note) {
  return (note.id !== noteID);
}

existingNotes.filter(noteDifferent);
```

`Array.filter(fn)` expects a callback function `'fn'` as a parameter, and will send the element `note` in this case, to said function.